# What is standard way to store wrapped cryptographic keys with necessary parameters?

Tags: javascript, cryptography

## Context

I am trying to implement a set to cryptography functionality, compatible between Node.js (as expected server environment) and modern browser.
Mostly it works as expected, except RSA-PSS keys import from Node to browser, but this issue is beyond the scope of this question.

## Problem

What I looking for is for an industry standard/spec to store encrypted key of any kind (symmetric or private) and related parameters.

For example, if key encrypted with a key derived from passphrase, how to store properly that information like algorithm id (PFKDF2 in this context, but this later can be changed), iterations count, salt), or encryption-specific parameters, like algorithm id as AES-256-GCM, and IV data.

I was hoping that webcrypto wrapKey and unwrapKey can give hint on that kind of standard, but all examples at MDN page seems to be assuming that storing this information together with this wrapped key data is beyond scope of what wrapKey and unwrapKey function do.

Looks like I just don't know how to properly to ask this question to web search engine. I expect that there is some industry standard or specification for that, plus I hope to avoid inventing yet another incompatible wheel.

Side note: I looking for some binary format, not JSON or other text representation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Eventually I researched it further and found that standard way to store the protected keys or "secrets" is DER-encoded data structures according PKCS#8 spec
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208 RFC 5208

There are plenty implementation of all that, either standalone, or as part of libraries like https://pkijs.org/ aka PKI.js